# SQL SERVER,Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 4 Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am Newbie at SQL Server.I am developing a database for a project,So i have a old database and I created a new one and now I am importing the arguments that is sitting at old database to a new one.But there is some tables that is giving me the violation key error.How can I solve this. Here are the scripts for the tables that matter :

```
Create Table TabProv
(

CodProvincia int,
DescrProvv Char (35),
DataHorC datetime,
DataHorA datetime,
CodOp1 varchar (6),
CodOp2 varchar(6),
CONSTRAINT PK_TabProv_CodProv PRIMARY KEY(CodProvincia)

);

Create Table TabMunicipio
(
CodProvincia int,
CodMunicipio int,
DescMun char(35) ,
DataHorC datetime,
DataHorA datetime,
CodOp1 varchar (6),
CodOp2 varchar(6),

CONSTRAINT PK_TabMunicipio_CodMunicipio PRIMARY KEY(CodMunicipio),
CONSTRAINT FK_TabMunicipio_TabProv FOREIGN KEY(CodProvincia) REFERENCES TabProv(CodProvincia)

);

Create Table TabLoca
(
    CodProvincia int,
    CodMunicipio int,
    CodLoc int,
    DescLoc char(35) ,
    DataHorC datetime,
    DataHorA datetime,
    CodOp1 varchar (6),
    CodOp2 varchar(6),

    CONSTRAINT PK_TabLoca_CodLoc PRIMARY KEY(CodLoc),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TabLoca_TabMunicipio FOREIGN KEY(CodMunicipio) REFERENCES TabMunicipio (CodMunicipio),
    CONSTRAINT FK_TabLoca_Prov FOREIGN KEY(CodProvincia) REFERENCES TabProv (CodProvincia)


);
```

So after creating this 3 news tables , I am popultaing this new table dbo, with the values that are sitting at old database table,the table Municipio works like charm,but the table Prov gives me this error:

```
DELETE FROM GESTHANDNET2015v1.dbo.TabMunicipio; 

INSERT INTO GESTHANDNET2015v1.dbo.TabMunicipio([CodMunicipio],[DescMun],[CodOp1],[CodOp2],[DataHorA]) 
SELECT T2.[CODMUN],[DESMUN],[CODOP],[CODOP2],[DATMOD] FROM
GestHandnet.dbo.TABMUN T2;

(0 row(s) affected) 
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 4 

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_TabMunicipio_CodMunicipio'. 
Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TabMunicipio'. 
The duplicate key value is (1). The statement has been terminated.
```

Please what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you read **all of the words** in the error message, it spells out pretty clearly that the problem is that you're trying to insert a duplicate key into the CodMunicipo column in TabMunicipio, and that doing so violates the primary key constraint. How much clearer can **You're trying to insert a duplicate value in [this exact field] in [this exact table]** be?

Comment: so Thanks Matt, I only want to know wich one of them is set to 1.CodProvincia or CodMunicipio?Because I tried to insert only one of them and the error continues

Comment: you have in definition `CONSTRAINT PK_TabMunicipio_CodMunicipio PRIMARY KEY(CodMunicipio)`  This is the primary key therefore `CodMunicipio` is the one with two records in GestHandNet.dbo.TaBMUN.CodMunicipio having more than 1 record with a CodMunicipio of 1.

Comment: The error message tells you which table you're trying to add the duplicate value to, as I told you in my previous comment. INSERT and UPDATE are the only statements that check primary key constraints, as they're the only statements that can affect them.

Comment: Thanks matt...and by the way I am using google translator so is hard to get it at first.Thanks google and thanks Matt

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear. You're inserting more than one row into `dbo.TabMunicipio` with the same primary key value. Specifically, more than one row where `CodMunicipio` is set to 1.

There must be multiple rows in `GestHandnet.dbo.TABMUN` where `CODMUN` is 1. When you do the INSERT, that tries to put multiple rows into `dbo.TabMunicipio` where CodMunicipio is 1, which you've disallowed with your primary key constraint:

```
...CONSTRAINT PK_TabMunicipio_CodMunicipio PRIMARY KEY(CodMunicipio),
```

Answer (score 1):

CodProvincia is not the problem.  It does not have a unique constraint. FOREIGN KEY is not a unique constraint.  The problem is CodMunicipio.

Lots of people want to know which one (of the 1).  SQL unfortunately does not give you that information.  If you cannot inspect the data directly then your option is a mirror table with no unique constraints to find the duplicates.

In the case of your insert pretty easy

```
SELECT T2.[CODMUN], [DESMUN],[CODOP], [CODOP2], [DATMOD] 
  FROM GestHandnet.dbo.TABMUN T2 
 WHERE T2.[CODMUN] = 1;
```

You can use [IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) for it to display an error but continue and insert unique rows.

Data would be truncated is another error that it would be nice to know which row (or column).

Comment: Matt ,Frisbee,Ken White,xQbert and Raj More,BIG Thanks for the explanation

Comment: You should check an answer.  I have no problem if you give the answer to Matt.   But let people know the question is answered.